# How can you make this directory creator a while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I made this directory creator (inspired) and I was thinking about how I could make it into a while loop, and if you exit the program it stops. Any tips?

```
def main():

    dirName = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=111))

    try:
        # Create target Directory
        os.mkdir(dirName)
        print("Directory " , dirName ,  " Created ") 
    except FileExistsError:
        print("Directory " , dirName ,  " already exists")        


    if not os.path.exists(dirName):
        os.mkdir(dirName)
        print("Directory " , dirName ,  " Created ")
    else:    
        print("Directory " , dirName ,  " already exists")

    dirName = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=111)) 



    try:
        os.makedirs(dirName)    
        print("Directory " , dirName ,  " Created ")
    except FileExistsError:
        print("Directory " , dirName ,  " already exists")  



    if not os.path.exists(dirName):
        os.makedirs(dirName)
        print("Directory " , dirName ,  " Created ")
    else:    
        print("Directory " , dirName ,  " already exists")    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly. If we copy-pasted that we wouldn't be able to run it and we wouldn't be able to guess where thigns should/shouldn't be indented

Comment: why do you execute similar code blocks 4 times, once with checking, once without, twice overall ?

Answer (score 0):

You could create another function that runs `main` in an infinite `while True` loop. Then wrap that function call in a `try: ... except KeyboardInterrupt: pass` clause after the `__name__ == __main__` check.

Comment: please flag the answer as correct if you feel like it solved your issue or answered your question =)